# Join query using 5 different tables

Tags: sql, firebird

```
tbl_vehicle_mst
--------------------------
v_id    v_no    v_make
1   Bus-01      Tata
2   Bus-02      Volvo
3   Bus-03      Tatra

tbl_route_mst
--------------------------------
r_id    r_no    r_from  r_to
1       01      A       B
2       02      A       C
3       03      A       D

tbl_vehicle_route_map
-----------------------------
vrm_id  r_id    v_id    
1       1       2
2       2       1


tbl_driver_mst
-------------------------------
d_id    d_code      d_name
1       drv-1       John
2       drv-2       Ram
3       drv-3       Gomesh

tbl_veh_driver_map
------------------------------
vem_id   v_id   d_id
1        1      2
2        2      3
```

I have 5 tables as shown above. Using some kind of join query I want the Output to be as shown below. Since 5 different tables are involved; I am greatly confused as how the desired output can be reached. Every time I sit down to write the join query, everything gets mixed up in my head and I get confused and unable to write join query. I would be highly obliged to anybody who would point me in the right direction perhaps with some sample sql query. Thanks in advance.

Required Output

```
route       v_no        driver_name
------------------------------------
A to B      Bus-02      Gomesh
A to C      Bus-01      Ram
```

The following below i have tried so far

```
SELECT 
(SELECT b.d_name FROM tbl_veh_driver_map a, tbl_driver_mst b WHERE a.d_id = b.d_id) AS DRIVER_NAME,
(SELECT DISTINCT(b.r_from || ' - ' || b.r_to) AS RT FROM tbl_veh_driver_map a,tbl_route_mst b,tbl_veh_route_map c WHERE a.v_id = c.v_id AND c.r_id = b.r_id) AS ROUTE,
(SELECT a.v_no FROM tbl_vehicle_mst a,tbl_veh_driver_map b WHERE a.v_id = b.v_id) AS v_no,
FROM tbl_veh_driver_map
```

Comment: Please give an example of something you tried; it might not be right, but might not be that far from being right.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySql? Please add the relevant tag to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I missed something this looks like a simple set on joins on the pk/fk pairs. The query below should give you the result you want:

```
select 
  r_from || ' - ' || r_to as route, 
  v_no, 
  d_name as driver_name
from tbl_route_mst as r
join tbl_vehicle_route_map as rm on rm.r_id = r.r_id
join tbl_vehicle_mst as v on v.v_id = rm.v_id
join tbl_veh_driver_map as vd on vd.v_id = v.v_id
join tbl_driver_mst as d on d.d_id = vd.d_id
```